# What's the difference between "panza arriba" and "al sol" in the song "Al agua pato"?

Tags: letras-de-canciones, interpretación

The second verse of the children's song "Al Agua Pato" goes like this:

> Un poquito panza arriba
> y otro poquitito al sol.
> Cada cual a su manera
> goza de la natación.  ([source](https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=2283982))

I understand the third and fourth lines to be summarizing the previous two, saying that there are different ways to enjoy swimming.  But, lines one and two seem to say the same thing!  That is:

- "panza arriba" – belly facing upward
- "al sol" – facing the sun (i.e., upward)

Am I misinterpreting lines one and two?  Do they actually describe two different ways of swimming?

## Castellano

El segundo verso de la canción infantil "Al Agua Pato" dice:

> Un poquito panza arriba
> y otro poquitito al sol.
> Cada cual a su manera
> goza de la natación.  ([fuente](https://www.musica.com/letras.asp?letra=2283982))

Entiendo que las líneas tres y cuatro son una resumen de las dos anteriores, diciendo que hay diferentes maneras de gozar de la natación.  Pero me parece que líneas una y dos significan lo mismo.  O sea:

- "panza arriba" – barriga hacia el cielo
- "al sol" – hacia el sol (i.e., arriba)

¿Quizás mi entendimiento de las líneas una y dos está mal?  ¿Realmente describen dos maneras distintas de nadar?

Comment: It looks like you found a wrong version of the song. What I found says "un poquito panza **abajo** y otro poquitito al sol". You are right to be confused. see here https://youtu.be/BHmn7wedL1k?t=1m20s

Comment: well, there are several wrong versions around too. :-) https://youtu.be/MJOXMiZ9qBo?t=41s

Comment: Seems like the two versions are about equally common, if Google search results are any indication... [806 for arriba](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Un+poquito+panza+arriba%22+al+agua+pato&oq=%22Un+poquito+panza+arriba%22+al+agua+pato) and [846 for abajo](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Un+poquito+panza+abajo%22+al+agua+pato&oq=%22Un+poquito+panza+abajo%22+al+agua+pato). Seems like there must be a way to explain so many "wrong" ones...

Answer (score 1):

Children's songs (and sometimes songs, in general) are not always "accurate". They only have to sound good.

In this case you are right in your translations.

- "panza arriba" – belly facing upward
- "al sol" – facing the sun / facing up

As we discovered there are other more consistent versions where they say "abajo" instead of "arriba" so describing two really different ways of swimming.

[Video of the "abajo" version](https://youtu.be/BHmn7wedL1k?t=1m20s)
[Video of the "arriba" version](https://youtu.be/MJOXMiZ9qBo?t=41s)